# Transcendental solution to system of equations

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a set of polynomials:$$P_1(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=0,$$
$$P_2(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=0,$$
$$\vdots$$
$$P_k(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=0$$
is a system of equations with coefficients over $\mathbb{Z}$, and there are functions $$y_1=f_1(x),\dots,y_n=f_n(x)$$ which satisfy the those equations.

Question:  is any function of $x$, that is, any of those function $$y_1=f_1(x),\dots,y_n=f_n(x)$$ algebraic? or are $$y_1=f_1(x),\dots,y_n=f_n(x)$$ all algebraic?

Suppose zeros of $A$ is $Z(A)$, $\forall (x,y_1,\dots,y_n) \in Z(A)$, $x,y_1,\dots,y_n$ are all algebraic numbers?

**EDIT:** Does there  exist zeros of $A$  such that $\forall (x,y_1,\dots,y_n) \in Z(A)$, $x,y_1,\dots,y_n$ are all algebraic numbers?

Does there  exist function of $x$, that is, any of those function $$y_1=f_1(x),\dots,y_n=f_n(x)$$ such that $y_1=f_1(x),\dots,y_n=f_n(x)$ are all algebraic?

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f_2(x)=\cos(x)$ are transcendental but satisfy $P(x,f_1(x),f_2(x))=0$ for $P(x,y_1,y_2)=y_1^2+y_2^2-1$.

The concept you have described is *algebraic dependence*.

Comment: I have to edit the post slightly to include more questions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An other similiar example is $f_1(x)=\sin(x)+x$ and $f_2(x)=\cos(x)-x$ , $P(x,f_1(x),f_2(x))=0$ for $P(x,y_1,y_2)=y_1^2+y_2^2-1-2x^2$.